# How to select last 24 hours Doctrine_Query with Symfony?

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony1, doctrine

I am trying to get all users who logged in last day. How can I do it ?

In yml the table for users is Timestampable.

I am using Doctrine 1.2 in Symfony 1.4.

```
Users:
  tableName:          users
  options:
    type:             InnoDB
    collate:          utf8_general_ci
    charset:          utf8
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
      updated:
        disabled: true
```

Comment: Do you have the table definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, unless you add a field where you update the record every time someone logs in. Timestampable provides you with "created_at" (record creation) and "updated_at" (record last updated).